# fundamental theorem of homomorphisms of Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I would like to prove the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms of Banach space.
Let $V$ and $W$ be Banach spaces.Let $f:V→W$ be surjective bounded linear map.
I could prove $T:V/ker f→W$(v modKerf→Tv) is continuous.

I understood $\ker f$ is closed in $V$, so $V/\ker f$ is a Banach space.
What I should do is to prove inverse of $T$ is continuous.

If I could prove **$T$ is bijective**, by using range theorem, I can finish.

Could you tell me the proof of **$T$ is bijective**?

If I could prove this, I would be able to prove a kind of analogy of the fundamental theorem of homomorphisms for Banach spaces. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the surjectivity of $f$ to prove that $T$ is surjective. Use the definition of $V/\ker f$ to show that $T(v) = 0 \implies v = 0 \pmod{\ker f}$, from which you can conclude that $T$ is injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the famous Open Mapping Theorem at your hand. By this, you know that $f:V\rightarrow W$ is an open map as it is surjective. Now by an elementary property of quotient maps of Banach spaces (only Normed linear space is enough though), openness of a bounded linear map is preserved under quotients, i.e. $T:V/ker f\rightarrow W$ is a bounded open surjective map.

Now you just need to show that $T$ is injective. This is very simple. If $T[v]=T[w]$ where $[v]$ is the equivalence class of $v\in V$ in $V/kerf$, you have $T[v-w]=0\implies f(v-w)=0 \implies v-w\in kerf$. Hence you have that $[v]=[w]$. Thus $T$ is injective. Thus T is an open continuous bijection, hence the inverse is continuous.

Comment: Could you tell me why T is surjective?

Comment: By your assumption, the map $f$ is surjective. So let $w\in W$, now there exists $v\in V$ such that $f(v)=w$. Hence by the definition of the map $T$, you have $T([v])=f(v)=w$. Thus T is surjective.